# Create a new variable conditioned to an external list

Tags: r

I am having some trouble creating a new variable in R in a dataframe conditioned to an external list of values:

```
# Sample dataframe 

employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
color <- c('blue', `green`, `red`)

data.frame(employee, salary, color)

#List of colors and categories 
color_categories <- list( cold = c("blue", "green"), warm = c("red", "orange"))
```

I want to create a new variable in the dataframe with the color category depending on the color chosen by each employee, so I want to get something like this result:

```
    employee  salary   color  category
1   John Doe  21000    blue   cold
2 Peter Gynn  23400    green  cold
3 Jolie Hope  26800    red    warm
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `tidyverse`:

-Use `bind_rows` on your `list` to create a `data.frame`, then `pivot_longer` so we can join on colors.Then rename `name` as `category` (result of `pivot_longer`)

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(employee, salary, color) %>% 
  left_join(bind_rows(color_categories) %>% pivot_longer(everything()), by = c("color" = "value")) %>% 
  rename(category = name)
```

This gives us:

```
    employee salary color category
1   John Doe  21000  blue     cold
2 Peter Gynn  23400 green     cold
3 Jolie Hope  26800   red     warm
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, I tried this solutions as I thought it was the simplest (since my actual dataset and lists are muuuch complex than the example I showed) but it did not work very well for me. Since the list of color categories is not homogeneous in terms of category items number, it shows me an error on the size compatibility among columns.

Comment: @anais_xis - if you provide sample data that reflects the category items, we might be able to tweak the solution to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say this is more tidy than package dependent solutions, but this is a solution in `base`:

```
color_categories <- data.frame(unlist(color_categories))
colnames(color_categories) <- "color"
color_categories$category <- gsub("[0-9]", "", rownames(color_categories))

merge(df, color_categories, by = "color") # df being the sample dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ifelse`

```
 df$category = ifelse(df$color == 'blue' | df$color == 'green' , 'cold', NA)
 df$category = ifelse(df$color == 'red' | df$color == 'orange' , 'warm', df$category)
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about an ifelse solution but since the list of items is very complex (the colors example I used is just a hiper simplified example) I do not think this would be an efficient option... (I may have like 220 values organized in categories in a list...)